# Android: OAuth signed requests

Tags: android, oauth, tumblr

Building simple Tumblr client.

Already done user authentication through browser and got token and tokenSecret.
But stuck on fetching [user info](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods). Are there any handy ways to build signed oauth requests?

Some libs usage example would be very helpful.

Comment: what you have tried to achive this can you provide some code?

Comment: Trying to get a user's Info by api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info url
but this requires some kind of OAuth signed request
have no idea how to build it. It's not simple Http post request but requires some additional params. Can't find out what exactly i need to set in headers or in entity. There must be easy way to make it with using some library...

Comment: see [this](http://code.google.com/p/tumblr-picture-viewer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/gmail/yesguxun/tumblr/ui/TestActivity.java?r=6) which maybe help you in solving current issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's easy to do with [oauth-signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) libarary.

Comment: [This link](https://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/#Google_Android) Says **IMPORTANT: Do NOT use the DefaultOAuth* implementations on Android, since there's a bug in Android's java.net.HttpURLConnection that keeps it from working with some service providers. Instead, use the CommonsHttpOAuth* classes, since they are meant to be used with Apache Commons HTTP (that's what Android uses for HTTP anyway).**